# my second user defined number in my calculator always starts with a leading zero how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, calculator

i created a basic calculator, but when i enter my second value, it always starts with a leading zero, but how can i fix it? e.g 5+05=10
its only the second value that has a leading zero. i am stil new to c# and programming so please help me. it is frustrating to see the leading zero the whole time. any feedback will also be appreciated.

```
       `

             namespace calc
           {
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to           within           a                 Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Double num01 = 0;

    int Operation = 0; 
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void num0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "0";
    }

    private void num1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "1";
    }

    private void num2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "2";
    }

    private void num3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "3";
    }

    private void num4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "4";
    }

    private void num5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "5";
    }

    private void num6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "6";
    }

    private void num7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "7";
    }

    private void num8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "8";
    }

    private void num9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "9";
    }

    private void aclear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = String.Empty;
        Operation = 0;
        num01 = 0;
    }

    private void ppoint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString (textbox1.Text + ",");
    }

    private void adiv_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        num01 = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
        textbox1.Text = "0";
        Operation = 1;
    }

    private void amultiply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        num01 = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
        textbox1.Text = "0";
        Operation = 2;
    }

    private void asub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        num01 = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
        textbox1.Text = "0";
        Operation = 3;
    }

    private void aadd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        num01 = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
        textbox1.Text = "0";
        Operation = 4;
    }

    private void aequal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Double num02 = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);

        switch (Operation)
        {
            case 1:
                if (num02 == 0)
                {
                    textbox2.Text = "Can not divide by zero";
                    textbox1.Text = String.Empty;

                }
                else
                {
                    textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(num01 / num02); 
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble     (textbox1.Text) * num01);
                break;
            case 3:
                textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(num01-Convert.ToDouble      (textbox1.Text));
                break;
            case 4:
                textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble      (textbox1.Text) + num01);
                break;
        }
    }
   }
   }  `
```

Comment: The user was asked to open a different question for his request for additional information on the original topic. Now that he does the question gets closed. That is not nice...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of `TrimStart()` function that will eliminate all the leading zeros on your string. Anyway it seems that when you enter the first value and you hit a operation key, you are setting the value of the main textbox to the string "0" and when you press again a "number button", you just append the number to the textbox that already has the value "0". That is why your second number has leading zeros.

For example in this function:

```
private void adiv_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    num01 = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
    //textbox1.Text = "0"; YOU ARE SETTING THE TEXTBOX TO THE VALUE "0"
    textbox1.Text = ""; TRY THIS
    Operation = 1;
}
```

If you want to use TrimStart() function you will have to do something like this:

```
textbox1.TrimStart('0');
```